# How to form and minimise custom features for classification in supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, gradient-descent

I am having an issue in understanding how to form the features based on particular math formula, and how to adjust the weights with.
The aim is to draw ellipses for each unique category of points. Ellipse keeps inside as much of possible selected type of dots, and as little as possible other types (in the picture attached selected yellow ones).
Here is the a formula, with 5 variables, based on which we can draw any ellipse.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/65hlgysuy7

I can make a model and calculate based on the data set whether the particular point is within the ellipse (score less than 0) or outside, and create accuracy based loss function, or just to use cross entropy for the loss function. Then i could find derivative for cross entropy, but then what's next? How basically i could adjust the weights in such case?

The the big question how i could manipulate those variables (in the link a,b,c,l and h) to form different models, and optimize them with gradient descent (if thats the appropriate technique for such task)?

Can someone please explain me the logic of how custom features in such case can be formed and weights found with gradient descent?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with ellipses, you may indeed tackle the problem through an optimization procedure.

The gradient-descent algorithm consists in computing gradients around the current solution (set of `(a, b, c, l, h)` and change these values depending on the derivatives. It could work, but also be stuck in local minima; a classic solution is to run the algorithm multiple times, with different starting points. There are other, more efficient but also more complex, optimization algorithms (genetic algorithms, simulated annealing) that you may need to look at if gradient descent performs badly.

Now, with this kind of problem, there may be more efficient techniques. As already stated in *quester*'s answer, the most intuitive solution would be support vector machines. But the ellipse shape you're trying to draw makes me think of **Gaussian Mixture Models**. This is because the iso-probability of a Gaussian multivariate distribution is an ellipsoid. See an explanation of how it works in [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html). In a more general approach, you could replace the optimization algorithm by the Expectation-Maximization procedure (which is the one implemented in `sklearn`'s Gaussian Mixture Models).

Once a Gaussian bivariate distribution has been fitted on the data, you can retrieve the equation of ellipses from the distribution means and covariances. I don't have means to test the following code right now, but you should be able to adapt it and make it work. Starting from the a `sklearn` `GaussianMixture` named `gmm`, the ellipse coefficients as in your example can be retrieved from each component with:

```py
#  i would be the i-th cluster
b = gmm.means_[i][0]
c = gmm.means_[i][1]
covs = gmm.covariances_[i]
# cst will allow sizing the ellipsis, depending on the targeted confidence interval
l = np.sqrt(covs[0,0]) * cst
h = np.sqrt(covs[1,1]) * cst
eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(covs)
try:
    a = -np.arctan(eigvec[1, 0]/eigvec[0, 0])
except ZeroDivisionError:
    a = 0
```

The definition of `a` in your example is strange so I'm not quite sure of the calculation of a, but adding an integer number of $\pi/2$ to that value and/or switching its sign should do the job.

Comment: Hi Romain, thanks for the answer. I need to try Mixture models. With SVM problem is that when you have 2 classes to separate with, than it draws something else. If talking about ellipse (it will draw only one ellipse for which ever class SVM chooses). Another issue if you have no boundaries than it draws quite big ellipse that basically doesn't fit within screen

Comment: Gaussian Mixture Models might be the way to go in this problem, can you please update the answer with some example with SKLEANR how to convert Gaussian Mixture Models output to ellipse coordinates (a, b, c, l, h). Then it would be the full answer

Comment: I added the explanation on how to retrieve the parameters based on the Gaussian bivariate distribution moments. Can't test the code right now but it should be something close to this.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine

polynomial kernel of degree 2, with C coefficient >.1 but you would have to figure it out based on your data

I can provide more info on request

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, SVM might do the trick in classifying and giving the right answer. But i would like to know more how can i manipulate the parameters based on the function, if one would like to implement some rough approach from scratch in order to see the process - how ellipse (or another figure) is fitted and redraw that figure and variations in different system. Basically how to implement adjustment of weights for each parameter in simple way and from sratch

Comment: @Darius read about gradient descent and how gradients flow through neural-network (calculate it yourself for 2 layers to get the idea), then you will know how it works, whole Andrew Ng lecture 9 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0twSSFZN9Mc

Comment: if you could have a try in explaining it with examples on how would i need to form features and use gradient descent for the example i posted (ellipse fitting) that would be a perfect answer